# Batch file to search for string in most recent file

Tags: string, batch-file, recent-documents

I have alot of log files which need searching for certain strings and was wondering if I could make a batch file to automate this job for me? All I need it to do is locate the most recent log in a certain directory then search for the string in that file.

I have found the below code on this website which works great to open the most recent log file but unfortunatly I dont know enough about batch programming to amend the code to search for the string and display the line.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`dir /b /o-d`) do @call "%%i"&goto :eof
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Add a findstr to the end:

```
or /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`dir /b /o-d`) do findstr searchforthisstring %%i
```

What this is doing is searching for "searchforthisstring" the files found by

```
dir /b/o-d
```

Which list files (/b = simply name not any other info and /o-d reverse date order

Answer (score 2):

At first, set which is the file you want. If `/od` doesn't work, try `/o-d`...

`for /f %%i in ('dir \path\to\files\ /b /od') do set myfile=%%i`

... and pay attention because `myfile` will come without pathway.

Then use `for /f "tokens=*"` to read each line of the file fully, and `findstr` to search for your `STRING`...

`for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (\path\to\files\%myfile%) do (echo %%i | findstr STRING >> OUTPUTFILE)`

If you want `OUTPUTFILE` to be overwritten everytime you run the code, use a single `>`.

If you don´t want a file, but see the output on screen,  just delete the `>> OUTPUTFILE` code.